# UIWebView: disable Select, Copy, Paste on textarea

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm using a textarea in UIWebView. I want to disable Copy, Paste and Select for the textarea. But manual text input should work. -webkit-user-select: none is not a solution because it completely disables the textarea so that I can't input any text. So my question is how can I disable Copy, Paste and Select on textarea without disabling text input.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Why would you want the user to be able to type but not select copy or paste into a text area? I get very frustrated with web sites that do stuff like this, and I generally don't visit them again if I can help it.

Comment: This is not a website. I'm using a UIWebView to render a custom functionality that looks like a part of native app.

Comment: Funny, I am doing exactly the same thing.  Did you ever find the solution, @andr111?